# How to make sure all async calls finish before proceeding within nested foreachs

Tags: typescript, rxjs

First of all, I know this has been answered many times before, but I've been unable to find how to implement it for this specific scenario.

On one side I have a method similar to this

```
getSomeInfoFromAnApi(param1: number, param2: number): Observable<any> {
    // Call some REST API and return an Observable
  }
```

On the other side, the method is being called somewhere else this way:

```
data.forEach(graphic =>
      graphic.series.forEach(serie => {       
        if (serie.channelValueType === 'string') {
          this.myService.getSomeInfoFromAnApi(graphic.modelId, serie.channelId).subscribe(myResponse => {
            // this is much more complex, just keeping it small for the sake of the example
            // but the important thing here is that a member of the 'serie' item is being modified
            serie.points = myResponse;
          });
        }

      })
    );

// graphics$ is defined as a BehaviorSubject
this.graphics$.next(data);
```

The issue here is that the call to **next** on the BehaviorSubject is happening much earlier than it should, because **getSomeInfoFromAnApi** is an async call.

What is the best approach to make sure that the call is only happening after all the elements in the data collection have been processed, meaning that all the possible calls to getSomeInfoFromAnApi have responded and executed the subscribed code.

**Initial approach**

This is what I have implemented so far, based on some of the answers I've found on stackoverflow, but I'm sure there must be a better approach:

```
data.forEach((graphic, dataIndex) =>
      graphic.series.forEach((serie, seriesIndex) => {     
        
        if (serie.channelValueType === 'string') {
          this.myService.getSomeInfoFromAnApi(graphic.modelId, serie.channelId).subscribe(myResponse => {
            
            // this is much more complex, just keeping it small for the sake of the example
            // but the important thing here is that a member of the 'serie' item is being modified
            serie.points = myResponse;

            if(data.length === dataIndex + 1 && graphic.series.length === seriesIndex + 1) {
              this.graphics$.next(data);
            }
          });
        }
        else {
          if(data.length === dataIndex + 1 && graphic.series.length === seriesIndex + 1) {
            this.graphics$.next(data);
          }
        }

      })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this could work well for your scenario.

Instead of using a BehaviorSubject and manually emitting into that stream, we can create a stream from your `data` using `from()` to emit the array items individually, use `mergeMap()` to handle subscribing to your api calls, then use `toArray()` to combine all results into a single array once all calls have completed.

```
graphics$ = from(data).pipe(
  mergeMap(graphic => from(graphic.series).pipe(
    filter(series => series.channelValueType === 'string'),
    mergeMap(series => this.myService.getSomeInfoFromAnApi(graphic.modelId, series.channelId).pipe(
      map(myResponse => ({...series, points: myResponse}))
    ),
  ),
  toArray()
)
```

Comment: Note: I'm short on time right now, so this is just a quick response to give you a direction to go in.  It's not tested and might have some typos.  I'll be back online tomorrow :-)

Comment: I just did a small test and indeed it is emitting each array item individually after the api calls finished. This seem to be a suitable solutions, thanks.

On the other hand I'll like to find a way of maintaining the BehaviorSubject if possible.

If no other answer emerge, I'll mark this one as accepted.

Comment: Curious to know why you specifically want to use behavior subject.

Comment: BizzyBob it was just because that's the way the data is currently binded, but looking at @Rafi Henig code it looks that it will be more efficient to just change the way I'm binding the data, right?

Comment: The view should just be binding to an observable.  Doesn't matter if it comes from a BehaviorSubject or not.  In your simple example, it doesn't look like you need anything provided by the subject, it just seemed like an extra moving part in your code.  I'd say you only need BehaviorSubject if you need to "manually" emit items in to the stream.  If all emissions original from an array element, I see no need for BehaviorSubject.  If you're simply looking for the "default value" behavior, you can use a `startWith()` inside your pipe to provide a default.

Comment: In my example I used `from(data)`, but if your `data` is the result of a different http call (or other source that returns an observable), you wouldn't even need to use that first `from`.  It could be something like this: `graphics$ = getData().pipe(...);`

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example of how it could be implemented (`BehaviorSubject` is left in place):

```js
from(data)
  .pipe(
    mergeMap(graphic => from(graphic.series)
      .pipe(
        filter(series => series.channelValueType === 'string'),
        mergeMap(series => this.myService.getSomeInfoFromAnApi(graphic.modelId, series.channelId)
          .pipe(
            map(points => ({ ...series, points }))
          )
        ),
        toArray(),
        map(series => ({ ...graphic, series }))
      )
    ),
    toArray(),
  )
  .subscribe(graphics => this.graphics$.next(graphics))
```

Comment: This looks right to me, but would you say it is more efficient If I just let the BehaviorSubject away an go with the solution proposed by BizzyBob?